# how to write WebFlux filter which needs to pass Rest body for authorization service call

Tags: spring-boot, filter, spring-webflux

I need to implement an authorization filter for WebFlux spring-boot application. To invoke authorization service I need to get url, queryParam, headers and body.
 I can get first 3 properties from ServerRequest of the HandlerFilterFunction, however I have problem with body.  The authorization call requires all four parameters:

```
 Principal authorization(String method,Sting requestUrl,Map<String, ListValue> headersMap, String body) throws ServiceException
```

The method throws exception if user is not authorized to execute the method otherwise  returns Principal object.

The method is never called when filter is executed because I don't have any subscriber to mono object:

```
public class WebFluxAuthorizationFilter implements HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> {
  @Override

  public Mono<ServerResponse> filter(ServerRequest request, HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> handlerFunction) {

    String method = request.methodName();
    String requestUrl = request.uri().toString();
    HttpHeaders headers = request.headers().asHttpHeaders();
    Map<String, ListValue> headersMap =  new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
        ListValue grpcList = toListValue(entry.getValue());
        headersMap.put(entry.getKey(), grpcList);
    }
    Mono<Principal> mono = request.bodyToMono(String.class)
            .flatMap(body -> {
                return Mono.just(authorization(method, requestUrl, headersMap, body));
            });
    return handlerFunction.handle(request);
}
```

I have the same issue if I use  WebFilter instead of HandlerFilterFunction
What should I do  to get access to body and run authorization method shown above ?
The current code does not invoke authorization() because lambda  body -> ...  is never called.
Please let me know how filter should be written to  get the body and use during filter execution .

Comment: First of all, why do you need to write your own filter? What kind of token is in the body?

Comment: I need to invoke authorize() method and pass url, parameters, headers and body from request to the  method. The body is application/json object 
Do you know any known filter which I can customize?

Comment: When you say ”authorize method” what is that. Something custom?

Comment: If you are refering to springs authorization managment, you need to explain more about what type of request you are getting, whats in the body. Writing custom security solutions are bad practice. Are we talking jwt, tokens, etc.